# Bitnami WAMP Apache fails to start

Tags: apache, bitnami

I went through many posts on the issue, however did not found a solution.

When I try to start the Apache Server on Bitnami WAMP it fails.

```
`C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.39-0\apache2\bin>httpd.exe
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its acces
s permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its acces
s permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
`
```

When I try to the wampstackApache service from Windows Services I get below given error -

[Windows - Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNjXy.png)

[image]

```
Windows could not start the wampstackApache on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 1.
```

The options I tried are as under -

1. Changed the port 443 from `httpd-ssl.conf` to 543  - Didn't work.
2. Changed the port 80 from `httpd.conf` to 88 - Didn't work.
3. Checked the port using `netstat -ano` - No ports used above 543 or 88 found in the list*(those ports were free to use)*.
4. Uninstalled Skype completely - Didn't work.
5. Restarted Apache using`httpd.exe -k restart`, Unistalled and rebooted and re-installed using `httpd.exe -k Uninstall`, `httpd.exe -k install` - Didn't work.
6. Disable SSL mode by going to `httpd.config` file and commenting `#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so` and also commented `Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` - Didn't work
7. Tried to run service using `httpd.exe -k runservice` - Didn't Work
8. Went to windows services-> Properties -> Log On ->This Account (Entered Admin username and password) - Didn't work.
9. Went to windows services-> Properties -> Log On ->Local System Account - Didn't Work

Did someone else also faced this and has a solution. Thanks

Comment: Which Windows version are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Comment: And I assume that you are executing the command with administrator privileges, right?

Comment: Yes, all commands with Admin privileges.

Comment: The httpd-ssl.conf file is not being used. Could you confirm that you are not using more than one Listen 443 directives?

Comment: I have changed the port to 5443 which is not used by any other service, I checked it in Netstat - a

Comment: hi; did you manage to find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue in a Windows Server 2012 machine. The server "suddenly" rebooted because of some update and after that the Apache doesn't start at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution that worked fine for me on Windows 7 machine.

Step 1 - Download TCView [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview)

Step 2 - Open Services and Locate "wampstackApache"

Step 3 - Run TCPView.Exe (as an Administrator)

Step 4 - Kill the process ntp. [Kill the Process ntp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK2Zz.png)

Step 5 - Start the "wampstackApache" from services. And the htttp.exe will start

[HTTPd.Exe started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIVOg.png)

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: not working for me in WinServer 2012.  Still cant find out what is blocking Apache from binding to the 443 port

Comment: Now I found my solution: somehow the IIS was activated in the Server at the same time and was taking over the 443 port I guess...and Apache couldnt use it so it was flunking and didnt started.  Problem fixed here.

Thank you for suggesting the use of TCPView; it helped figure it out

Comment: I so appreciate it when people answer their own questions with answers that work, thanks a lot! Worked like a charm